# Javascript equals === not working as expected

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2

I am using Ionic2 and Typescript to develop an app.

I have the following code:

```
  public showTick(message: Message): boolean {
      console.log('showTick: '+message+'  '+message.readByReceiver+'  '+this.senderId+'   '+message.senderId);
    if (message && message.readByReceiver === true && this.senderId && this.senderId === message.senderId) {
      console.log('showTick(' + message.content + '): return true');
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

It outputs the following:

> ```
> showTick: [object Object]  true  P8   P8
> ```

I would have expected it to get inside the `if` statement and also print:

> ```
> showTick(xxx): return true
> ```

Is there something wrong with my use of `===`?

Any advise appreciated.

p.s. This is the `Message` model:

```
  interface Message {
    _id?: string;
    chatId?: string;
    senderId?: string;
    ownership?: string;
    content?: string;
    createdAt?: Date;
    changeDate?: boolean;
    readByReceiver?: boolean;
  }
```

**UPDATE**

I change the code to:

```
  public showTick(message: Message): boolean {
    console.log('showTick: ', message, message.readByReceiver, this.senderId, message.senderId);
    if (message) {
    console.log('showTick1 ');
      if (message.readByReceiver === true || message.readByReceiver === 'true') {
    console.log('showTick2 ');
        if (this.senderId) {
    console.log('showTick3 ');
          if (this.senderId === message.senderId) {
            console.log('showTick(' + message.content + '): return true');
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

And get the following ts error (`message.readByReceiver === 'true'`):

> ```
> ERROR in ./app/pages/messages/messages.ts
> (275,46): error TS2365: Operator '===' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'string'.
> ```

**UPDATE**

The problem seems to be that a `boolean` type object is holding a `string`, so the following fixes it.

```
if (message.readByReceiver === true || message.readByReceiver+'' === 'true')
```

Two issues:

1. This fix seems like a hack to me.
2. I am not sure why the `boolean` is holding a `string`. This is an
   object coming from a Meteor database defined as `boolean`.

Comment: please tag accordingly.

Comment: @Nina, what must I tag?

Comment: [off-topic] `message.readByReceiver === true` why not just `message.readByReceiver`?

Comment: It's unclear whether `readByReceiver` is `true` or `"true"` (a string)… Use `console.log('showTick:', message, ...)` instead of concatenating everything into one string.

Comment: @Mr_Green, I tried that without success.  I don't know Javascript well enough to understand the details. Maybe someone else can advise.

Comment: @deceze, thanks for the advise, I am testing that now.  I am from a Java background where objects are strongly typed.  I guess in Javascript they are not.

Comment: From your above console, `message.readByReceiver` is clearly an object so it is not equal to `true`. That is why you weren't able to see the console inside the if statement.

Comment: Add a tag for typescript for one. ;) --- Also, like @deceze said, use `console.log(a,b,c,d)` instead of using `+`.

Comment: @Mr_Green I don't think that's true. Look at `message+'  '+message.readByReceiver`

Comment: Having a lot of stuff inside one condition is not good to find a possible bug. 
First I would split all the conditions with parenthesis to prevent unexpected behaviours.
You should also use debug, or a simple  `console.log` to print each condition's part, to figure out if anything has a value that you were not expecting.

Comment: You need to figure out why a value you thought is a boolean is actually a string. Not work around this mis-typing with more hacks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to start off with some debugging techniques to provide or gather some more information. One in specific, is going to be the advice put forth by @andrecanilho and @deceze in the question comments.

You need to break down your if statement in to multiple outputs to figure out where your logic is breaking down:

```
console.log(message.readByReceiver === true)
console.log(this.senderId === message.senderId)
```

After diagnosing the output of those two statements, our (andre, deceze, and I's) guess is that one of them will be false ... leading you to a solution that you can either resolve yourself, or possibly provide more feedback to the Stack Overflow Community.

**UPDATE**

You can not compare a type boolean (true) to a type of string ('true') in Typescript.

Change this line:

```
if (message.readByReceiver === true || message.readByReceiver === 'true')
```

to:

```
if (message.readByReceiver === true)
```

This function should help you diagnose where your logic is breaking down:

```
public showTick(message: Message): boolean {
    console.log(message.readByReceiver === true);
    console.log(this.senderId === message.senderId)

    if (message && message.readByReceiver === true && this.senderId && this.senderId === message.senderId) {
      console.log('showTick(' + message.content + '): return true');
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```